# Independent units in pure number fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{t})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

**Theorem:** In [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02941425) of Frei and Levesque, they correct the proof of a result of Halter-Koch and Stender:

Define the real pure algebraic number field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(\omega_n)$ for $\omega_n=\sqrt[n]{D^n\pm d}>0$ (the $\pm$ sign is fixed), where $d,D,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $d|D^n$ and $D^n\pm d$ is not a $k^{\text{th}}$-power positive integer for $k|n$. Let $\epsilon_{n,k}=\frac{(\omega_n-D)^k}{\omega_n^k-D^k}$. Then the set $\{\epsilon_{n,k}: k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}, k|n\}$ is an independent system of units in $\mathbb{K}$.

**Background:** I am looking specifically at computing units of algebraic number fields of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{t})$ for odd primes $p$ (any infinite family in $t\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, with $p$ fixed). Unfortunately, the above result gives only one unit $\frac{(\omega_p-D)^p}{\omega_p^p-D^p}$.

**Question:** Are there results on obtaining at least one other independent (non-torsion) unit?

**Note:** For irreducible $x^p-t$ there is one real root $\sqrt[p]{t}$ and $p-1$ non-real complex roots $\zeta_p^i \sqrt[p]{t}$ for $i=1,\ldots,p-1$ and $\zeta_p=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$. Then by Dirichlet's Unit Theorem, the unit rank of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{t})$ is $1+\frac{p-1}{2}-1=\frac{p-1}{2}$. Thus I am especially interested in $p=5$ where there can be at most two independent units.